# Windows 10 close button bug when scaling is set to System Advanced

Tags: windows, scaling

I have this bug in my program, and many other program's

The close button misses one pixel, which makes you click trough the close button, and close the windows behind it. (Really annoying).

No scaling

[image: No scaling]

System Advanced scaling

[image: Scaling]

As you can see there is this small white line next to the close button which can be clicked trough.

Is there any fix for this?
(Its on basicly all applications using Advanced Scaling)

In my scenario i use 200% windows scaling combined with the Advanced Scaling setting.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bug or if it's been fixed, but what are the chances that a user is going to click within one pixel along the edge to close and then be confused if the window behind was clicked instead? At one pixel off, I'd probably figure I was one pixel off in my click. Seems like an extreme corner case not worth being too concerned about.

Comment: No, when the window is fullscreen. You move your mouse fully to the right corner of your screen (because thats really easy). And then click X (everyone i know does that atleast its just faster since you cant misclick (atleast if this bug wasn't there) ). And that is the exact 1-2 pixel(s).